# unable to install yacas with Rstudio

Tags: r, yacas

I already downloaded Yacas on my windows. I first installed package Ryacas directly from Rstudio but no yacas functions can be run.
I later ran this command and got the following errors:

```
> devtools::install_github("r-cas/ryacas", build_opts = c("--no-resave-data", "--no-manual"))
Downloading GitHub repo r-cas/ryacas@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEpL65w\remotes58d46bf01207\r-cas-ryacas-ea52235/DESCRIPTION' (684ms)
-  preparing 'Ryacas': (1.4s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (1s)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories (501ms)
-  building 'Ryacas_1.1.3.9002.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’ as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'Ryacas' ...
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Ryacas'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/Ryacas'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\MyName\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK-Ryacas\Ryacas\libs\x64\Ryacas.dll to C:\Users\MyName\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\Ryacas\libs\x64\Ryacas.dll: Permission denied
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Name~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEpL65w/file58d4192555cc/Ryacas_1.1.3.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have also tried these:

```
> system.file(package = "Ryacas", "yacdir") : install.packages('Ryacas')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/Ryacas_1.1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1739652 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

package ‘Ryacas’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeGHfz9\downloaded_packages
Error in system.file(package = "Ryacas", "yacdir"):install.packages("Ryacas") : 
  argument of length 0


> yacasInstall()
Error in yacasInstall() : could not find function "yacasInstall"


> yacas("n := (10 + 2) * 5")
Error in yacas("n := (10 + 2) * 5") : could not find function "yacas"


> Set(ns, (10 + 2) * 5)
Error in Set(ns, (10 + 2) * 5) : could not find function "Set"
```

How to run/install ryacas?

Update:

There are two R packages for yacas. Some references online refer to the old package. Some old commands are still useful just make sure we have downloaded the old package. Also, we cannot use the yacas commands on the official manual directly with R interface. We have to do something like yacas("...") or some yacas commands specifically for R.

Comment: Ryacas is on CRAN so you should be able to just do `install.packages("Ryacas")` .  Also there is a separate earlier version on CRAN too. `install.packages("Ryacas0")`  Both include yacas so you don't need to install that separately.  Suggest exiting entirely from R first and starting over with a fresh session.  Also `yacasInstall` was used in very old versions but is no longer needed as yacas is included.

Comment: I already ran `install.packages("Ryacas")`. Package should be installed. But I cannot use any yacas functions.

Comment: Then your installation of R is messed up.  Remove R  and all packages entirely and reinstall it.

Comment: I just uninstalled R and reinstalled. Same errors `could not find function "yacas"`

Comment: There is no function called yacas in Ryacas.  There is such a function in Ryacas0.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Ryacas/versions/0.4.1/topics/yacas http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf

Comment: @nems, That is from over 10 years ago and would correspond to the  Ryacas0 package with a zero on the end modulo any changes in the last 10 years.  For example, 10 years ago you had to install yacas separately but now it is included.  You can find information without downloading the whole package  on the CRAN.  home pages: https://cran.r-project.org/package=Ryacas and https://cran.r-project.org/package=Ryacas0